# react-native-webrtc unable to create RTCPeerConnection

Tags: react-native, webrtc, peer-connection

I am trying to create a basic RN app with react-native-webrtc, but I am unable to create a RTCPeerConnection class instance.

```
import {RTCPeerConnection} from 'react-native-webrtc';

const App: () => React$Node = () => {
   const configuration = { "iceServers": [{ "url": "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302" }] };
   const pc = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
   ...
   return(<>)
}
```

Having the error:
[image]

What could be a reason for not being able to create an instance of RTCPeerConnection class? All dependencies have been installed.

Comment: In which platform are you getting this error? iOS or Android?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention. I have it on iOS

Comment: Can you verify if you can see `RCTWebRTC` in `Library`? Looking at your issue, it's most likely a linking issue. Everything looks fine on Js.

Answer (score 0):

Note, that { "url": ... } is deprecated, you should use { "urls": ... } instead.